# Letting anonymous user to see fields?

Tags: users

I just created a content type with a field:images.
Then I added some content and I create a View to show these content. Then the view shows the images (from the images field)
Everything works fine but when I logout the anonymous user can not see the images.

As you can see in this picture I have "checked" Access content for anonymous user. But it doesn't work...

[image: view picture].

What I need to do to make the images visible for anonymous users is to have 'checked' View field_images. You can see the picture.

[image: view picture]

my question: do I need to checked on every field I create to make them visible to anonymous users? Is there any way to set that any new create field should be visible to anonymous users.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no field permission module installed, all fields are always visible. So if you don't want to restrict *any* fields, then disable the content permissions module.

Once such a module is installed, it works as implemented by that module. And there is no way for such a module to guess the permissions you want (should it be visible to auth users only, or anon users too.. maybe only a specific role?), so it can only chose the safe way and does not grant anything automatically.

That is consistent with all other permissions, when you install a new module.

Comment: Thanks berdir. I had Content Access module enabled, as you said I disabled but now the images are not visible, maybe I need to delete and re-create the nodes again to rewrite their permissions? I tried flushing all caches but nope...

Comment: solved! when creating new content all fields are visible.

Comment: Strange, I don't know why this would happen.